# Mysql Query to Get The Orders Those having All Statuses Except Delivered

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called as order_items those having following columns.

- id, order_id, status, created_at, updated_at.
- status values lies in 0,1,2,3,4,6,7
- I need to retrive all order ids those can have any status like for example either [0,1] or [0,1,2,3] or [3,4,6] or [0,1,2,3,4,6] except 7.

Comment: And what did you try? Did you maybe try using `WHERE status IN (0,1,2,3,4,6)`

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT order_id
FROM order_items 
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING !SUM(status = 7);
```